# Android- GridView items not in sequence

Tags: android

I have a problem with gridview.
Each item of gridview contains some data(such that image,text etc)
when i am creating view by checking condition i.e. if(convertView==null) then the item of gridview became random mean they are not in sequence.
And if i use if(true) for creating view then scrolling of grid is not smooth.

Anyone can help me????
Thanx  :)

Comment: becuase `View (row) creates every time even if view is not null`

Comment: If view is not created every time then some item in grid view is repeating and items are not in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The getView() implementation of the adapter of the gridView would get called for n number of times where n is the size of the data set. So you would not have to do a check like :

```
if (convertView == null)
```

This will be taken care of by the getView() itself. Also, you could do this check if you want your convertView to be of a certain class and if its null then create a new layout from an existing layout.xml file.